# Vue Daily Calendar with specific content (Vuetify)

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuetify.js

Is it possible to add specific content to the daily calendar using Vuetify?
I would like add data table for every day without intervals (1AM, 2AM etc.), but it doesn't work.

I tried:

```
<template v-slot:day-body="{ date, week }">
    specific content for selected day here...
    <v-data-table></v-data-table>
</template>
```

If this is not possible, is there any **other solution** to add a daily calendar (front-end)?
I can't find a similar example anywhere.

**Demo code** [here](https://codepen.io/noobmaster2137/pen/ZELLOoe)

**HTML:**

```
<div id="app">
  <v-app id="inspire">
    <v-row class="fill-height">
      <v-col>
        <v-sheet height="64">
          <v-toolbar
            flat
          >
            <v-btn
              outlined
              class="mr-4"
              color="grey darken-2"
              @click="setToday"
            >
              Today
            </v-btn>
            <v-btn
              fab
              text
              small
              color="grey darken-2"
              @click="prev"
            >
              <v-icon small>
                mdi-chevron-left
              </v-icon>
            </v-btn>
            <v-btn
              fab
              text
              small
              color="grey darken-2"
              @click="next"
            >
              <v-icon small>
                mdi-chevron-right
              </v-icon>
            </v-btn>
            <v-toolbar-title v-if="$refs.calendar">
              {{ $refs.calendar.title }}
            </v-toolbar-title>
          </v-toolbar>
        </v-sheet>
        <v-sheet height="600">
          <v-calendar
            ref="calendar"
            v-model="focus"
            color="primary"
            :events="events"
            :event-color="getEventColor"
            :type="type"
            :show-interval-label="false"
            @click:event="showEvent"
            @click:more="viewDay"
            @click:date="viewDay"
            @change="updateRange"
          >
            <template v-slot:day-body="{ date, week }">
              <div class="body-content">
                specific content for selected day here
              </div>
            </template>
          </v-calendar>
        </v-sheet>
      </v-col>
    </v-row>
  </v-app>
</div>
```

**Javascript:**

```
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  vuetify: new Vuetify(),
  data: () => ({
    focus: '',
    type: 'day',
    selectedEvent: {},
    selectedElement: null,
    selectedOpen: false,
    events: [],
  }),
  mounted () {
    this.$refs.calendar.checkChange()
  },
  methods: {
    viewDay ({ date }) {
      this.focus = date
      this.type = 'day'
    },
    getEventColor (event) {
      return event.color
    },
    setToday () {
      this.focus = ''
    },
    prev () {
      this.$refs.calendar.prev()
    },
    next () {
      this.$refs.calendar.next()
    },
    showEvent ({ nativeEvent, event }) {
      const open = () => {
        this.selectedEvent = event
        this.selectedElement = nativeEvent.target
        setTimeout(() => {
          this.selectedOpen = true
        }, 10)
      }

      if (this.selectedOpen) {
        this.selectedOpen = false
        setTimeout(open, 10)
      } else {
        open()
      }

      nativeEvent.stopPropagation()
    },
    updateRange ({ start, end }) {
      const events = []

      const min = new Date(`${start.date}T00:00:00`)
      const max = new Date(`${end.date}T23:59:59`)
      const days = (max.getTime() - min.getTime()) / 86400000
      const eventCount = this.rnd(days, days + 20)

      for (let i = 0; i < eventCount; i++) {
        const allDay = this.rnd(0, 3) === 0
        const firstTimestamp = this.rnd(min.getTime(), max.getTime())
        const first = new Date(firstTimestamp - (firstTimestamp % 900000))
        const secondTimestamp = this.rnd(2, allDay ? 288 : 8) * 900000
        const second = new Date(first.getTime() + secondTimestamp)

        events.push({
          name: this.names[this.rnd(0, this.names.length - 1)],
          start: first,
          end: second,
          color: this.colors[this.rnd(0, this.colors.length - 1)],
          timed: !allDay,
        })
      }

      this.events = events
    },
    rnd (a, b) {
      return Math.floor((b - a + 1) * Math.random()) + a
    },
  },
})
```

**Example image:**
[image: example image]

Answer (score 2):

You can set `:interval-count = 0` for `v-calendar` and load the data table below each day separately on a different component that changes according to the date selected.

Comment: The interval has been hidden, but the table is not displayed. Can you take a look at this code (Calendar + Data table)? https://codepen.io/noobmaster2137/pen/QWdqOGq Here is also working table code: https://codepen.io/noobmaster2137/pen/wvgrPre

Comment: https://codepen.io/indritkello/pen/KKaXQaz I think the problem is that your DataTable was inside v-calendar. We have to update it onchange of date now.

Comment: Thank you for your help. I will try to solve the data update.

Comment: Glad I could help :)